# How can I align JSpinners with other elements in a vertical JToolBar?

Tags: java, swing

I have an initially-vertical `JToolBar` and I add a button, a few `JLabel`s, and a few `JSpinner`s to it. For some reason, the `JSpinner`s get shoved over to the left relative to all the other components, which looks pretty strange and also makes the `JToolBar` wider than it needs to be. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that I need (for some reason) to call

```
spinner.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```

I guess it's set to right aligned by default.